# How does one solve the islands/gaps problem using android room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to solve this but I'm sadly unable to. 
Let's say the table looks like below and i would like to create groups of consecutive numbers. How would the code look like in this simple case? 
| id | value |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 9 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` always increment with no gap, you can just use aggregation:

```
select min(value) as min_value, max(value) as max_value
from mytable
group by id - value
order by min(value)
```

Else, we can generate the proper incrementing id with `row_number()`:

```
select min(value) as min_value, max(value) as max_value
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn - value
order by min(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions LAG() and SUM():

```
select id, value, sum(flag) over (order by id) grp
from (
  select *, coalesce(value <> lag(value) over (order by id) + 1, 1) flag
  from tablename
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=348be2c73820b66181be0ef3f995b31e).
Results:

```
> id | value | grp
> -: | ----: | --:
>  1 |     1 |   1
>  2 |     2 |   1
>  3 |     3 |   1
>  4 |     5 |   2
>  5 |     6 |   2
>  6 |     8 |   3
>  7 |     9 |   3
```